# Зустрітися чи надибати

Tags: вживання-слів, різниця-між-словами

У тексті йдеться про поневіряння, з якими зустрілася/які надибала/в які потрапила людина. Яке дієслово вжити?

Comment: Ще варіанти: «на які натрапила», «які собі знайшла».

Comment: Будь ласка, намагайтеся ставити точні запитання. Йдеться про це конкретне слово чи про використання жаргонізмів і просторічних виразів узагалі? В якому контексті? В офіційному документі ви навряд чи напишете «я здибала N», а у блоґу/соцмережах це запросто годиться.

Comment: мова про поневіряння. Текст близький до художнього, але мова не про те. Чи є відмінності у значеннях цих дієслів або це точні синоніми?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У [СЛОВНИКУ УКРАЇНСЬКОЇ МОВИ](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=38462&page=1200) знаходимо тлумачення слова "зустрітися":

> ЗУСТРІЧА́ТИСЯ, 1. з ким, кому і без дод. Зближатися, сходитися один з одним, рухаючись з різних сторін. // Траплятися на чиєму-небудь шляху, десь, у якомусь місці. // Стикатися з ким-, чим-небудь у житті, в роботі і т. ін. // перен., у сполуч. зі сл. труднощі, перешкоди і т. ін. Зазнавати чого-небудь, відчувати щось.

Отже, виходячи з наведених тлумачень, поневіряння можуть зустрітися і трапитись людині.

Альтернативну думку [висловлює](http://fakty.ua/166146-professor-nataliya-shumarova-zustr-chatisya-mozhut-lyudi-a-pomilki-traplyayutsya)  завідувач кафедри мови та стилістики в Інституті журналістики Київського національного університету імені Тараса Шевченка, професор Шумарова Н.П.:

> (Словами "зустрічатися і знаходитися") часто послуговуються, розуміють значення, але інколи вони опиняються, так би мовити, не на своєму місці. Це відбувається під впливом російської мови, в якій сполучуваність таких дієслів є дещо іншою. Обома мовами можна сказати: «часто зустрічатися з друзями» — «часто встречаться с друзьями», «знайшовся майстер, який зумів полагодити старовинний годинник» — «нашелся мастер, сумевший починить старинные часы». Але в деяких випадках повної відповідності конструкцій немає. В українській мові «зустрічатися» означає «спіткати когось у певному місці», тобто завжди йдеться про людей чи тварин. У казках вовк зустрічає лисичку, заєць — їжака тощо. Але інколи кажуть «Таку думку можна зустріти на сторінках газет». Це неправильно. Треба говорити «На таку думку можна натрапити на сторінках газет». Некоректно казати «У тексті зустрічаються помилки». Запам’ятаймо, що зустрічаються люди, а помилки трапляються.

Питання, чия думка авторитетніша, залишається відкритим. Але для сполучення дієслова *зустрітися* з іменниками, що позначають неістоту, також є вагомі підстави.